# Getting undefined from console log

Tags: reactjs

When I did a console.log(dbdata.user) it returned:

```
createdAt: "2020-11-17T04:32:17.934Z"
date: "2020-11-17T04:32:17.931Z"
displayname: "Batman"
followers: ["5fbb3879e8902d14f8c60448"]
updatedAt: "2020-12-02T14:58:17.880Z"
__v: 0
_id: "5fb35251888e8d081c06a7fa"
__proto__: Object
```

But when I did a console.log(dbdata.user.followers), it returned undefined. What am I missing here?

I am using useEffect and the state code:

```
 const [dbdata,setDBData] = useState({post:[],user:[]})

   useEffect(async() => {
        const response = await Axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/posts/allpost', {withCredentials:true})
        setDBData(response.data)
    }, [])
```

Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciated.

Comment: can we see more of your code

Comment: Basically, the useEffect api call did return the post and user dataset. I have added the code in the question section. Thanks

Comment: Here I can see the user is of type array. But you are trying to access followers by `user.followers` which is object-based syntax.

Comment: Two doubts, 1) where are you accessing console.log(dbdata.user.followers) 2) Your state is an object, if you want to set to post then it should be setDBData((prevState) => ({...prevState, post: response.data})), in-order to maintain the prev state of the component

Comment: Hi Dhruvi Makvana, what  I am trying to achieve here is to check if a value exists in the followers array,. For example, (dbdata.user.following === xxxxxxxxxxxxxx) ? "ok" : "not ok"

Comment: But your user is of type array for array invoking on key 'following' will be undefined.

Comment: you can't check an array like that so it should be dbdata.user.following.includes('xxxxxxx'), try this so if it has value it will return true

Comment: @Nat please post the entire code or sample code, so we can easily figure out and help you

Comment: hi Dileep Thomas, In tried that already but I got an error that says Cannot read property includes of undefined. here is what I have tried to do:  {
                                     
dbdata.user.followers.includes(xxxxxxxxxxxxx) ? "ok : "not ok"
 }

Comment: Is response.data is an array of objects or its an object, can you please add your response.data

Comment: const [dbdata,setDBData] = useState({post:[],user:[]}). An array of objects from post and user mongoDB

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the user to be of type Array in useState Hook. While you are trying to access `dbdata.user.followers` which points out that the user is of type object. Try changing the console statement to below.

EDIT:

You need to flatten the followers array before searching for values. Because it's an array inside an array.

```js
var user = [
  {
  'createdAt': "2020-11-17T04:32:17.934Z",
  'date': "2020-11-17T04:32:17.931Z",
  'displayname': "Batman",
  'followers': ["5fbb3879e8902d14f8c60448"],
  'updatedAt': "2020-12-02T14:58:17.880Z"
  },
  {
  'createdAt': "2020-11-17T04:32:17.934Z",
  'date': "2020-11-17T04:32:17.931Z",
  'displayname': "Batman",
  'followers': ["123"],
  'updatedAt': "2020-12-02T14:58:17.880Z"
  }
]

var followersArray = [];
user.forEach(e => followersArray.push(...e.followers))
console.log(followersArray.includes("123"))
console.log(followersArray.includes("00000"))
```

Comment: as mentioned in the  question the property is getting undefined, which means followers property doesn't exist, if its an array at-least it will be printed out. So let Nat add the snippet where he access it, may  be something else

Comment: He has cleary pointed out in question that  `I did a console.log(dbdata.user) and it is giving an answer` and in that snippet we can see `followers` property.

Comment: yep, in that case at-least it should print the array isn't, obviously it won't print undefined, since if its a single user it can be an object also isn't

Comment: hi Dileep Thomas, it is an array of users but because it is still in dev so there is only one user at the moment. Thanks

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS if you are trying to access any key which is not present in the object/Array it will give undefined. Here he is trying to access `user.followers` and not user. So it will give undefined.

Comment: Thanks Dhruvi Makvana, I did managed to get it to work thanks to your code snippet. I end up with this code here:   const flattenArray = () => {
           const list = []
           userData.user.push(e => list.push(...e.following))
           setFollowData(list)
   }